# Django URL tag not working - NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-url-reverse

I know we aren't supposed to use stackoverflow for debugging but i've been trying to fix this in the last 10 hours and I feel hopeless, my apologies.

```
#main project urls.py:
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('accounts/',include('employee.urls')),
    ...
]...

#employee.urls:
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('employees/', views.display_employees),
    path('edit/<str:employee_ssn>/', views.edit_employee),
    ...
]

#views.py - edit_employee being used only for testing by now
def display_employees(request):
    logged_user = request.user
    queryset = Employee.objects.filter(company=logged_user.company)
    context = {
        'employees': queryset
    }
    return render(request, 'employees.html', context)

def edit_employee(request, employee_ssn):
    context = {}
    emp = Employee.objects.filter(ssn=employee_ssn)
    
    context = {
        'employee_list': emp
    }
    return render(request, 'edit-employee.html', context)

#employees.html
<ul>
    {% for obj in employees %}
    <li>{{ obj.name }}</li>
    <li>{{ obj.ssn }}</li>
    <li>{{ obj.email }}</li>
    <li><a href="{% url '/accounts/edit/' obj.ssn %}">edit</a></li><br>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

#edit-employee.html
<ul>
{% for obj in employee_list %}
    <li>{{ obj.name }}</li>
    <li>{{ obj.ssn }}</li>
    <li>{{ obj.email }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

When it is clicked on `edit` it says:

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value: Reverse for '/accounts/edit/' not found. '/accounts/edit/' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

But if the url `http://localhost:8000/accounts/edit/<employee_snn>/` is typed on the browser, `edit-employee.html` renders normally. It also says the error is in my base template at line 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use the "*pattern*" in the [**`{% url … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url). You should give the view a *name* and then use this to resolve the url, so:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # …
    path('employees/', views.display_employees),
    path('edit/<str:employee_ssn>/', views.edit_employee, name='edit-employee'),
    # …
]
```

and then you can use this as parameter in the `{% url … %}` tag:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'edit-employee' obj.ssn %}">edit</a></li><br>
```

The idea of using an `{% url … %}` tag is that you can easily change the path patterns. As long as the name remains the same, and the parameters, it will still be able to resolve the template path.

Comment: I was trying something like this, insetad of just adding the view name I was also adding the pattern at url tag. Thank you so much